# Craft/Construct attachment using MailKit

Tags: c#, windows-services, email-attachments, mailkit, mimekit

I could not find this question anywhere.

Is it possible to craft attachment using MailKit without saving it local?

I have application linked to database and I am making Windows service for sending emails.

I read data from DB and I would like to craft .json attachment inside program and send it via mail using MailKit without saving that attachment local.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with mailkit, but I'm guessing somewhere it expects a `Stream` of some kind to write the attachment to, so you could just provide it with a `MemoryStream` instead of something like a `FileStream`

Comment: Thanks for answer.

I forgot to mention that I am using Entity framework core for operations with DB.
Now, my plan is to convert Entity object to byte array, read that byte array into the MemoryStream and then serialize MemoryStream to JSON object and send it as file attachment using MailKit.

Is all of that even possible ?

Comment: I wouldn't do it like that, I'd load the entity from the DB, serialize it to JSON, create a `MemoryStream` out of that string, and send that to MailKit, serializing a MemoryStream to JSON doesn't do what you want it to

Comment: Ok, I will try that.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

MimeKit allows reading from and writing to MemoryStreams (and other non-File-based streams).

You can also construct messages where the content of attachments and such are stored only in memory and not on disk.

The BodyBuilder.Attachments collection allows adding attachment data as byte[] and Streams (which includes allowing MemoryStreams). The `fileName` parameters in these `Add()` methods is only to provide a file name to set on the attachment.